# Why does the ammeter show a reading of 0?

Tags: voltage, current, voltage-regulator

Why is the rating of ammeter in the common wire zero? Electrons that are moving from the negative end of v1 can travel through the common wire back to the positive end of v1.

[image: idk]

The ammeters AM1 and AM2 have internal resistance of 100 Ω; the ammeter AM is "ideal".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't current flow through the common part of a circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/205895/why-doesnt-current-flow-through-the-common-part-of-a-circuit)

Comment: The "rating" is the maximum value it can display. I think you mean the "reading". Anyway you can't connect ammeters like that without burning something.

Comment: If you consider an analog meter with some resistance, then what is the difference in potential for the middle ammeter?  Right is at 0V.  Left is?

Comment: This schematic in the question appears to be from the answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/680831/101063 where the answer has the text _Let's now replace the "dead" resistors by "live" ammeters with intentionally increased internal resistance of 100 Ω_. Showing an ammeter connected but with an assumed internal large resistance is confusing.

Comment: Put a voltage meter over the ammeter that says 0A and observe the voltage. It is unclear if you simply ask why current is 0 (it must be, as the meter says there is no current through it and the other two meters confirm it) or what is the reason why it must be zero (multiple electrical engineering formulas such as KCL or Ohm's law).

Comment: Voltage divider. Here is a [video demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJvyb_WujZg) of almost the exact same circuit.  Coincidentally, it's why a US home split-phase AC mains can maintain +/- 120 V even after the neutral is broken when both legs have equal loads, but the voltage goes out of control when the loads are no longer equal, creating mysterious problems.

Comment: @nani chan, Sorry that I didn't pay attention to your question in your already deleted "answer". But I've been thinking all this time about how to answer you. I did it an hour ago in the form of a "reversed" [step-by-step story](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/680831/61398). Please look at the end of my answer and think about the written. You can answer me by writing about this phenomenon in the body of your question. With this you can contribute to its reopening.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist - Please avoid being seen to encourage site misuse. Suggesting to the OP to respond to your answer *elsewhere* by "writing about this phenomenon" in the question *here* will likely get deleted as changing this question too much after it has received answers already. || While it's unfortunate that someone with low points score wanted to ask you about your answer elsewhere, but couldn't, don't try to bypass that limitation which is deliberate to avoid comments from low-score users. They just need to get more points, then comment *in the right place*. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson, I hadn't thought about the fact that they didn't have the opportunity to comment, I was even angry that they didn't do it...

Answer (score 1):

Start with V1. Current from it flows from the positive terminal through SW1 and AM1. AM1 reads 100 mA, that 100 mA has to return to the negative of V1 and there are two paths it can take, through AM2, SW2 and V2, or through the Ammeter in the center (AM).

AM2 is also showing 100 mA through it, so at the junction of AM1, AM2 and AM there is 100 mA entering from AM1 and 100 mA leaving through AM2, leaving no current to go through AM. For there to be any current through the center meter the other meters would need to read different values from each other.

The ground symbol can be ignored for this, it's connected to a single node in the circuit so current cannot flow into or out of it. You could leave it out and it wouldn't affect the rest of the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

When the resistances on both legs of a bipolar power supply are equal, there's no current flow to the center-tapped ground. In this case, we can also say that we have a balanced load. This is an useful conclusion that has practical applications not only in DC circuits, but its AC version can also be used to understand the neutral current in split-phase AC mains in US homes, and can be further extended to analyze 3-phase AC grids.

To see why, one simply has to understand a voltage divider. It's even easier to see if one is aware of the Wheatstone bridge.

### Open-Circuit Voltages

Let's first consider the open-circuit voltages in the original circuit. In the circuit below, when there is nothing connected to the voltage sources, the voltage across the top leg is 1 V, with respect to the center point (or the *center tap* of the power supply), the voltage across the bottom leg is -1 V (an equal and opposite polarity) with respect to the center tap. Watch the polarity of the voltmeters. Because we are measuring the voltages with respect to the center tap, you should connect the "negative" side both voltmeters to the center, it means flipping the direction of the second voltmeter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyEzS8m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, let re-consider the same circuit, but the voltages are now measured with respect to the negative pole of V2. In this case, with respect to the negative side of V2, we see that the voltage at the top is +2 V, voltage at the middle is +1 V, and the voltage at the bottom is 0 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFkj0Xm.png)</sup>

Thus, if the center-tap is unused, the two 1 V voltage sources are equivalent to a 2 V voltage source for a load connected across both legs of the power supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZubRO.png)</sup>

### Voltage Divider

Then, let's see what happens when two resistors of equal values are connected to a single 2 V power supply. The voltage across a resistor connected in series is:

$$ \text{V}_{\text{R2}} = \text{V}_1 \cdot \frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1 + \text{R}_2} $$

Using this equation, we can see that when two resistors of equal values are connected in series, the voltage at the center point is always one half of the supply voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6EGt7m.png)</sup>

Finally, we replace the 2 V voltage sources with the original bipolar power supply of two 1 V voltage sources.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftJxaam.png)</sup>

Note the voltage at the center tap of the power supply is 1 V, the voltage at the center tap of the resistor is also 1 V. Thus, if we connect the center of the voltage sources and the resistors together, no current flows.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhawecm.png)</sup>

### Applications

#### Wheatstone bridge

The circuit shown below is known as a Wheatstone bridge.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQXorjm.png)</sup>

One resistor is an unknown resistor, other resistors are known resistor and at least one is variable. When the variable resistor is adjusted so that:

$$ \frac{R1}{R2} = \frac{R3}{R4} $$

The ammeter indication will be zero.

This is independent from the the accuracy of the voltage source or the ammeter, the only requirement is an ammeter capable of accurately detecting the existence or absence of current to see whether the bridge is balanced.

Thus, this circuit was used in ancient time to accurately measure resistors when accurate voltage references didn't exist. Today, it's still sometimes used for signal conditioning in analog circuits.

By convention, bridge circuits are drawn as a diamond shape, so a more familiar form is:

[image: Wheatstone bridge]

#### Split-phase AC mains in the US

In the United States, AC mains voltage at home is 240 V, but it's provided in two polarities as +120 V and -120 V with respect the center tap of the transformer (which is also connected to the Earth ground). This is known as a "split-phase" system.

[image: split-phase AC]

The advantage of this system is that each split phase acts like a 120 V AC supply in its own, but can be cascaded in series to provide 240 V.

If the neutral is broken in an accident, the connection to the center tap is lost and each phase can no longer maintain 120 V. However, if by chance, the loads on both legs of the split-phase are equal, the neutral current will be zero and it doesn't matter whether the neutral is connected or not, giving the illusion that there's no fault. However, when the loads become unbalanced because some appliances are turned on or off, overvoltage will appear on one phase, damaging appliances. Meanwhile, undervoltage will appear on another phase. Thus, a broken neutral can create mysterious problems depending on what appliances are turned on.

Here is a video demonstration of the same principle using the DC bipolar power supply that I've already explained.

- [Demonstration and explanation of the effects of an "open neutral."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJvyb_WujZg)

Answer (score 0):

The voltage source in the upper loop will cause a 100 mA current flowing to the right in the center leg, while the voltage source in the lower loop will cause a current of 100 mA flowing to the left in the center leg.  These two currents cancel, resulting in no current in the center leg.